# Table Column Structure/Change Analysis with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I download an excel file everyday. It contains sales result information. But sometimes the format(columns) changes. E.g.,

```
Column <As-is> A B C D <Changed> D C E F
```

So, I want to make a report on the change with SQL. It will be like this.

- Column A has been deleted.
- Column B has been deleted.
- Column C has been moved from third to second position.
- Column D has moved from 4th column to 1st Column.
- Column E has been added in the 3rd column.
- Column F has been added in the 4th column.

What I want to analyze is not the rows(data) but just column(structure).
I am trying to do this by connecting SQL to the Excel file to manipulate the data within an Excel file with SQL language.

I made an excel file of two rows: first is the previous column structure and the second is current column structure. The two column structure probably will be two rows of a table and I need to find a way to get the analysis report that I want to make.

Comment: MS SQL. Not because I want. But because I heard that connecting to an Excel file with SQL required me to us MS SQL. And actually, I don't have a dbms installed. But I use an RPA tool named WinAutomation generating an SQL connection with an Excel file. The tool enables me to manipulate the data within an Excel file without having a dbms installed.

Comment: A DBMS that can make use of the ACE drivers can read an `xlsx` file; not just SQL Server. The problem you have here, however, is that your file isn't being maintained well. If you don't have a static definition for your file, working with them becomes very hard.

Comment: The short answer is - you probably cannot do this in tsql. A person can look at 2 sets of information and (usually) determine these sorts of changes. That can be very, very complex logic. You must look at the structure of the data and the content as well. Surely there are columns that contain similar values. A number is just a number but it might be an ID, a quantity, a price, a sequence number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to explain in a comment.  First, I don't see the utility of what you want to do.  Input data for databases should be more stable.  Hence, it seems like your real problem is something different -- and you haven't explained it.

Second, the results are ambiguous.  If you want to go from ABC to CBF, which is the "right" set of changes?

- Remove A in Column1
- Add C to Column1
- Remove C from Column3
- Add F to Column3

or:

- Column A removed
- Column C moved to Column1
- Column F added to column3

All that said, you can compare the two columns using `information_schema`:

```
select ordinal_position,
       max(case when table_name = 'old' then column_name end) as old_name,
       max(case when table_name = 'new' then column_name end) as new_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name in ('old', 'new')
group by ordinal_position;
```

I don't see how to simply transform this to the structure you want.  But if this is a real problem, I do have one recommendation which is to investigate Levenshtein distance.  You would need to adapt the algorithm to support strings rather than letters, but it might be what you want to accomplish.